# ES6 how to import module "onto" another module

Tags: ecmascript-6

I have already imported a `mapboxgl` module, then I am trying to import the second "submodule" geocoder like `import 'mapbox-gl-geocoder';` and like `import mapboxgl.Geocoder from 'mapbox-gl-geocoder';`, but that is obviously wrong approach, since I am only getting the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: mapboxgl is not defined`. How to do this right? Details below...

I am trying to use the [Mapbox geocoding example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-geocoder/) with ES6 (and webpack).

The example uses 2 mapbox js libraries like this (skipping non-interesting part of the file):

```
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.16.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v1.0.0/mapbox-gl-geocoder.js'></script>
...
<script>
   ...
   var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      ...
   });

   map.addControl(new mapboxgl.Geocoder());
   ...
</script>
...
```

So then I want to "translate" this to my project that uses ES6 (and webpack).

When I only use the main mapbox-script (mapbox-gl), I can use that nicely like this:

```
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
let map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    ...
});
```

But I am getting trouble when I try to include the "submodule" mapbox-gl-geocoder like this (I most probably import the second script the wrong way):

```
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
import 'mapbox-gl-geocoder';
let map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    ...
});
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.Geocoder());
```

How can I "add" the submodule to the main module? When I try this, I only get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: mapboxgl is not defined

Since it works nicely before I added the two lines `'import 'mapbox-gl-geocoder';` and `map.addControl(new mapboxgl.Geocoder());` I am guessing that I am importing incorrectly the second library.

Comment: And the 'trouble' is?..

Comment: Oh, thanks, added error in the question...

Comment: I tried `import mapboxgl.Geocoder from 'mapbox-gl-geocoder';`, but that is obviously wrong approach...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second package `mapbox-gl-geocoder` relies on `mapboxgl` global, a frequent case of halfhearted CommonJS module support.

Use [one of the several ways that Webpack provides](https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html) to expose `mapbox-gl` module exports as `mapboxgl` global variable. The good thing is that `mapbox-gl-geocoder` expects `mapboxgl` (not necessarily `window.mapboxgl`), this means that Webpack can inject `mapboxgl` local variable, and it will still work as intended.

Or create a helper module to do this independently of bundling environment. Create a file with a name like `mapbox-gl-helper.js`:

```
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
window.mapboxgl = mapboxgl;
export default mapboxgl;
```

Then use this it in the file where you need it like this:

```
import mapboxgl from './mapbox-gl-helper';
import Geocoder from 'mapbox-gl-geocoder';
...
```

Comment: When I try this:
`
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
window.mapboxgl = mapboxgl;
export mapboxgl;
import mapboxgl from './mapbox-gl-helper';
import Geocoder from 'mapbox-gl-geocoder';
`
I get the error 
``Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./components/app"``
...

Comment: `this means that Webpack can inject mapboxgl local variable`. How can I do that?

Comment: @EricC As mentioned here [https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html](https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html), there are several ways to do this in Webpack. You haven't provided your Webpack configuration, so pick the one that suits your configuration best. `ProvidePlugin`, `imports-loader`, `expose-loader` - they all do the similar job.

Comment: Finally got some sleep and got sober (that helps too) and now I understand better :) I wanted to use the help module. When I created the file `mapbox-gl-helper.js`with the 3 lines of code you gave. But I get one warning from my IDE saying that `statement expected` on the line with `window.mapboxgl = mapboxgl;`. And when I run webpack, it gives the error `Module build failed: SyntaxError: /app/mapbox-gl-helper.js: Unexpected token (3:7)` Any idea why?

Comment: Sure, it should be `export default mapboxgl;`. And depending on how the app is being built it may be necessary to use `const mapboxgl = require('mapbox-gl');` instead of `import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl'` for NPM modules. CJS/ES6 module coupling is a separate topic.

Comment: My problem almost similar to this one. Do you mind to help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37608118/uncaught-typeerror-fs-readfilesync-is-not-a-function

Comment: @estus I've started using the ```ProvidePlugin``` and that looks nice, but even now I'm importing the geocoder and I'm getting ```mapboxgl.Geocoder is not a constructor``` - did you find this too @EricC?

Comment: @HuwDavies See [the comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36531071/es6-how-to-import-module-onto-another-module/36534579?noredirect=1#comment60704417_36534579). It totally depends on how the modules are used in your project. If ProvidePlugin provides CJS module, and Babel/TS is configured to import ES6 modules, this won't work.